# Smart Slider 3 : Move slide By id with JavaScript

Tags: wordpress

I am using Smart slider 3 for carousel video slider. Its working fine by default.

I want to by default load **2nd slide of my slider**.I am using below link in reference.
https://smartslider3.helpscoutdocs.com/article/312-move-slides-with-javascript

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  n2ss.ready(8, function(slider){
    jQuery('.switch').click(function(){
        slider.slide(1);
    });
  });
});
```

I am putting my code in custom.js of my theme.
**Am i putting code at right place?**

I am getting error > Uncaught ReferenceError: n2ss is not defined
[image: Image of Eroor]

I tried to solve it with below referance link but still not able to solve it.
https://smartslider3.helpscoutdocs.com/article/485-n2-is-not-defined

Nexted Setting:

[image: Nexted Setting Image]

Comment: share your site url . may be the your script is not find the smart slider default scripts. you can check by source of site.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Slider 3.3 introduced a new JavaScript API. You should be able to switch to that slide with the following code:

```
N2R('#n2-ss-70', function($, slider){
    $('.switch').click(function(){
        slider.slide(1);
    });
});
```

Where 70 is the slider ID